# Determinant of a block matrix with $\mathrm{Id}$ and $0$ in the diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices

How to compute the determinant $\det A$ depending on $B$ and $C$, where

$$ A = \left(\begin{matrix}\mathrm{Id} & B \\ C & 0 \end{matrix} \right), $$

a) when $C$ is square, 
b) $C$ has more rows than columns

Comment: Hint: If $C$ has more rows than columns, then its rows are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 4):

The block determinant formula: if $A$ is invertible,
    $\det\begin{pmatrix}A& B\\ C& D\end{pmatrix} = \det(A) \det(D - C A^{-1} B)$

Answer (score 1):

*Hints:*

- note that $$\begin{pmatrix} \text{Id} & B \\
  C & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \text{Id} & 0 \\
  C & \text{Id} \end{pmatrix} \cdot\begin{pmatrix} \text{Id} & B \\
  0 & - C\cdot B\end{pmatrix}.$$
- furthermore, in general $$\det\begin{pmatrix}A& 0\\ C& D\end{pmatrix} = \det\begin{pmatrix}A& B\\ 0& D\end{pmatrix} = \det(A) \det(D)$$ and $\det (A\cdot B) = \det (A) \det(B)$ for square matrices $A$ and $B$

Comment: $\det (-C\cdot B) = \det (C) \det(B)$ ??

Comment: Determinant of a product of square matrices is the product of the determinants. But $\det(-C) = (-1)^n \det(C)$ for an $n \times n$ matrix.